# Create a text file on a host server from website

Tags: javascript, java, php, server, user-input

I am trying to attempt to give users the ability to write a text file to a directory on the website's host server. A usage case would look like:

1. User visits www.example.com/createtext
2. User types in a text bot what they would want to be saved, "Hello" for example
3. The server that the website is hosted on creates a text file in one of it's directories.
4. On the server, there is now a text file in C:/somedirectory/dailytexts/ with "Hello" written inside of it

I have currently written a simple page with a form that will take in text information and save it to a text file with the name of the current date.

```
<script language="Javascript">
    var time = new Date();
    var formattedTime = time.toLocaleTimeString();

    function download(filename, text) {
      var pom = document.createElement('a');
      pom.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + 

    encodeURIComponent(text));
      pom.setAttribute('download', formattedTime);

      pom.style.display = 'none';
      document.body.appendChild(pom);

      pom.click();
      document.body.removeChild(pom);
    }
</script>

<form id="form" class="topBefore" onsubmit="download(this['name'].value, this['text'].value)">
    <textarea id="message" type="text" placeholder="Hello" name="text"></textarea>
    <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Download Text File">
</form>
```

This simply downloads the text file to the user's computer. Instead, I would like the file to be created on the host machine.

Is there anyway to do this? In particular, with just JavaScript or Java. But if it has to be done with something like PHP then that would work too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*AFAIK, JS in the browser only lets you do stuff client-side and not modify server content without the use of... (for example) PHP scripts on the server-side.*

This solution *(now)* uses only HTML and PHP, with the need of JS eliminated.

HTML ***(modified)***:

```
<form id="form" class="topBefore" action="createtext.php" method="GET">
<textarea id="message" type="text" placeholder="Hello" name="name"></textarea>
<textarea id="message2" type="text" placeholder="Hello" name="text"></textarea>
<input id="submit" type="submit" value="Download Text File">
```

PHP: *(file named **createtxt.php**)*

```
if(isset($_GET['name']) && isset($_GET['text']))  {
    $filename = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9_-]#', '', $_GET['name']);
    $file = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/textfiles/$filename.txt";
    $f = fopen($file, 'w');
    fwrite($f, $_GET['text']);
    fclose($f);
    echo 'Success.';
}  else  {
    echo 'Error.';
}
```

The file creation requires two parameters - the filename and content, while only one `textarea` was provided in the question's HTML. So another is included now, for the filename.
jQuery/JS is removed. Instead, the form now sends the data over to createtext.php, which creates the file (`fopen`), writes the text (`fwrite`) and echoes "Success." - note two things here:

1. We're saving the text-file to a folder called `textfiles` in the same directory as `createtext.php`. The folder must exist from before - it will not be created automatically, and PHP will throw an error if it doesn't.
2. You can replace `echo 'Success.';` with other actions: like redirecting to another page or the same page (`header`), or `echo`ing/`readfile`-ing an HTML page.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you. I will try implementing this this week and see how it goes.

Comment: Did the code you posted work for you? I have been trying to get everything to work all day with no luck. But I also don't have my own test service to really test on and I am not sure if that is the reason it's not working for me.

Comment: @Stamden No - sorry, I've changed the code now - the JS had an extra set of brackets (and didn't work even after removing those brackets :/). This one works though (tested on XAMPP 7.0.5).